# Send message to specific contact through whatsapp from another app in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, whatsapp

Is it possible to send document to a specific contact through whatsapp directly from another app?

I know the contact ID. I don't want to open whatsapp via Intent.

```
const Whatsapp = () => {

    let formattedNumber = CustomerContact;
    let url = `whatsapp://send?text=hello&phone=${formattedNumber}`;

    Linking.openURL(url)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('WhatsApp Opened');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert('Make sure WhatsApp is installed on your device');
      });
}
```

I am sending messages directly but i also want to send a file located within my mobile device.